# Python How to Import xlsx file using numpy

Tags: python, csv, numpy, xlsx

I am having no trouble importing csv data using numpy, but keep getting an error for my xlsx file. How do I convert the xlsx file to csv or how to I import xlsx file to the x2 variable?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as pp
import numpy as np

#this creates a line graph comparing flight arrival time, arrival in queue, and processing time

x,y = np.loadtxt ('LAX_flights.csv',
                unpack = True,
                usecols = (1,2),
                delimiter = ',')

print("Imported data set arrival time")

x2 = np.loadtext ('First_Persons_PT.xlsx',
               unpack = True,
               usecols=(0))

print ("Imported start of processing time")


#y2=
#print ("Imported final time when processed")

pp.plot(x,y, 'g', linewidth = 1)
#pp.plot(x2,y, 'y', linewidth = 1)
pp.grid(b=True, which = 'major', color='0', linestyle='-')

pp.title('Comparing Time of Arrival vs. Queue Arrival Time, Queue Finish Time')
pp.ylabel('Arrival in queue (Green),Process Time (Yellow)')
pp.xlabel('Time of arrival')

pp.savefig('line_graph_comparison.png')
```

Here is the error

```
Imported data set arrival time
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fkrueg1\Dropbox\forest_python_test\Graph_time_of_arrival.py", line 13, in <module>
    x2 = np.loadtext ('First_Persons_PT.xlsx',
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loadtext'
```

The xlsx is just a single column of about 100 numbers

Answer (score 15):

```
import pandas as pd
WS = pd.read_excel('ur.xlsx')
WS_np = np.array(WS)
```

Using pandas is simpler

Answer (score 5):

The method's name is `loadtxt`, rather than `loadtext`. That explains the error that you report.

However, `loadtxt` won't be able to read an OpenXML .xlsx file. The .xlsx file is a binary format, and a rather complex one at that. You will need to use a module dedicated to reading such files in order to be able to read .xlsx files. For instance, `xlrd` and `openpyxl` can both read .xlsx files.

Depending on what your requirements are, it may be easier to supply a text file rather than a .xlsx file.

Comment: [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) will also work, you can get it from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl) using `pip install openpyxl`

Answer (score 3):

NumPy does not have any commmands to read Excel documents. Instead use [openpyxl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl) for OpenXML (`Excel >= 2007`) or [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) for xls and xlsx as [@David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29438816/4228275) suggests. You can use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to install either. From the [openpyxl documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) example:

```
>>> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>>> wb = load_workbook('First_Persons_PT.xlsx', read_only=True)
>>> print wb.sheetnames
['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3']
>>> ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
>>> use_col = 0  # column index from each row to get value of
>>> x2 = np.array([r[use_col].value for r in ws.iter_rows()])
```

[See my posts](http://poquitopicante.blogspot.com/2013/05/print-reading-lolitas-in-tehrans-lolita.html) on [reading Excel in Python](http://poquitopicante.blogspot.com/2013/06/xlrd-vs-openpyxl-round-ii.html).

Comment: [Pandas `read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) also works, and creates a dataframe that you can then [convert to a NumPy record array using `to_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html) which preserves dtypes or to an ND-array using either [`as_matrix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html) or [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html).

Comment: _EG_: `import pandas as pd; df = pd.read_excel('First_Persons_PT.xlsx'); x2 = df.to_records()`

Answer (score 1):

Note that, as of Pandas version 1.2.0, the top answer now throws an exception for xlsx files because the default reader engine (xlrd) only support xls files (see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). A simple solution is to set the engine to be openpyxl (you'll have to pip/conda install it first):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_excel('ur.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')
data_ar = np.array(data)
```